# How put order in multiple raster file in RasterMosaic in FME?

Tags: raster, fme-form, mosaic, sorting

I have couple of raster files which I want to mosaic in a specific order.
How I can do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**In FME 2020.1**

To order the rasters use the Attribute Creator and then assign a number (1,2 etc).

Then sort them by numeric (ascending)

[image]

Workspace template is available here
https://community.safe.com/s/article/alpha-compositing-blending-two-raster-images